# How to allow linter to resolve imports through Odoo's `odoo.addons`?

Tags: python, odoo, python-packaging

How do I set up my development environment so my IDE is able to properly resolve imports through `odoo.addons`?

In some cases in Odoo one may need to import Python objects directly from a file in **another custom module**. Take a module `some_module` as an example. In `some_module/models/some_model.py` there might be an import like so:

```py
from odoo.addons.other_module import some_class
```

This type of import is done throughout the Odoo source code, and everything is resolved without issues because the built-in Odoo modules are located directly under the `odoo/addons` directory which has an `__init__.py` file. However, since my custom modules are in a separate directory, the linter is obviously not able to resolve the imports.

What's the recommended way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use PyCharm, you can use the Odoo plugin to help IDE understand Odoo imports and more!

References:

https://odoo-ide.com

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13499-odoo

Comment: Some code suggestions for how to implement PyCharm might be helpful here!

Comment: This is fantastic... but unfortunately I use VS Code. I actually did use PyCharm before but I got totally fed up with the constant background processing it did all the time, slowing my development environment to a crawl.

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin I am the author of the Odoo plugin for PyCharm. An Odoo extension for VS Code is on my roadmap. I'll come back here to let you know when it's ready.